# How do you convert a signal that is either -5 or +5V to 0 or +5V, respectively

Tags: voltage

In my circuit I convert a 0 or 5V signal to a -5 or 5V signal using a schmitt trigger to get some hysteresis. However, I'd like to convert the signal back into a 0 or 5V. In effect, I'd like my schmitt trigger output to be shifted up. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Why not convert the original 0-5 V signal directly with a Schmitt trigger, as that seems to be the point of the conversion in the first place?

Comment: It may be better to post a complete circuit diagram and the higher level goals of the design.

Answer (score 1):

Given the obvious solution that Olin has proposed and, assuming you are somewhat "married" to the output that produces +/-5V, why not use a diode and resistor? The diode is in-series with the signal conducting positive voltages and the resistor is on the output of the diode to 0V. If you have fast signals, a BAS16 will probably do what you need with a 2k2 resistor to 0V. The downside is that the output will be more like ~ +4.5V to 0V. But if you can live with that then it saves you stripping the schmitt trigger apart and redoing it on a single supply rail. It won't be able to supply much power either BUT it's EASY and that was your question.

Comment: 1. How would I have to re-do my schmitt trigger to not change the range of the input? Presumably it is not as simple as just grounding the negative supply voltage? 2. I'm not quite sure how the diode/resistor solution works. When 5V is at the input of the diode, ~4.5 V is at the output from the small voltage drop of the diode. When -5V is at the input of the diode,  how does the output go to near 0V?

Comment: @Ben when -5V is at the input to the diode the diode acts like an open circuit and this means the resistor is dragging the signal outputted to 0V - the diode is reverse biased and prevents current flow from the -5V taking the output below 0V